# Display popup on selecting drop down list item

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a `dropdownlist` with 4 `list` items. I want to display a pop up if i select a list item. Also in the popup, I have to show a hyperlink which should navigate to another page. 
Please give me suggestions and guidance .

Thanks

Comment: as soon as possible?........ its not your project team........

Comment: @sylon Its an enhancement in my project. Since i am a fresher, I have no idea about popup. I am jus done with the dropdown.

Comment: This isn't a sight to get answers to your programming projects. Come here if you are stuck with some code and need help.  First try something on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add this script on your page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenWindow(query, w, h, scroll) 
    {
      var l = (screen.width - w) / 2;
      var t = (screen.height - h) / 2;

      winprops = 'resizable=0, height=' + h + ',width=' + w + ',top=' + t     
                  + ',left=' + l + 'w';
      if (scroll) winprops += ',scrollbars=1';
      var f = window.open(query, "_blank", winprops);
    }

    function OpenOnchange{
      //$(function () {
        //  $('#DropDownID').click(function () {
              OpenWindow('add your page path', 300, 300, true);
          //});
      //});
   }
</script>
```

call **OpenOnchange** funcation from you dropdownchange event for ex.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="MydropDown" runat="server" onchange="OpenOnchange();">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the script.I tried this.But its coming like,Once i click the dropdown arrow, I am getting the popup window.I want the popup after selecting the list item and I want to display the link in small popup window and if i click that link,it should navigate to another page. Thanks.

Comment: change height and width from 800 to what ever you want. add you have to add link on that page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

axpx:

```
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddldropdown" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddldropdown_selected">
       <asp:ListItem Text="sometext" Value="value"/>
```

codebehind:

```
   protected void ddldropdown_selected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddldropdown.SelectedValue == "value")
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Call my function",     "showpopup();", true);
    }
}
```

script:

```
  function showpopup() {
    $("#divid").fadeIn('slow');


  }
  function hidepopup() {
    $('#divid').fadeOut("slow");
  }
```

Create a div in your aspx page and design your popup with your requirements and pass the id to the script.